WordPress: Elementor gallery shows on preview but not on the site
The web site worked perfectly  yesterday, but today it does not show a gallery in a column. The gallery is a background of the column.
However, everything still works in the  Elementor's preview. In the preview, the gallery is here. But on the site address the gallery does not show. The error appears in every browser, with every Wordpress theme I tried.
I created a new page, where there is only the column with the gallery as background. This gallery shows on preview, but not on the live site.
I have WordPress version 6.5.2, every plugin is updated, theme is updated. The page, where this error appears, uses a plugin for fonts only. The rest of the site seems to be working.
I did "Regenerate CSS & Data". Does not help.
